# Change URL of posts and also Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

Right now I have changed the posts url using the settings -> permalink i.e `/blog/%postname%/` I have now added a CPT and using the rewrite `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-posts' ),` but the urls for this custom posts are now inherriting the /blog/ from the standard posts so the urls look like `/blog/custom-posts/post-title-here` when I just want it to be `/custom-posts/post-title-here`.

Anyone know of a quick fix to achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is to use 'with_front' => false in the rewrite array :)